# Push an array to another array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do this in js/jquery:

```
var events = new Array();
var $event1 = [id, name, starttime, startposition];
var $event2 = [id2, name2, starttime2, startposition2];
var $event3 = [id3, name3, starttime3, startposition3];
events["fistcolumn"].push($event1, $event2, $event3);
```

this doesn't work... can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You've posted no jQuery code, so not sure why you tagged this as jquery and not javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no associative arrays in javascript, you can use an object:

```
var events = {};
events["firstcolumn"] = event1;
```

Also, lose the $ in front of your vars, that is php syntax :)

Update:

For your events, you should probably also use objects:

var event2 = {
    id: id2,
    name: name2,
    starttime: starttime2,
    ...
};

Comment: "no associative arrays in javascript"? Sort of, but `var foo = []; foo['bar'] = "everything is fine"; alert(foo['bar']);` does not give an error. `bar` actually becomes a *property* of the array but outwardly it amounts to the appearance of association, hence indexed and associative behaviour can be exhibited in one array simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

```
var events = {}, //lets try that with an object?
    event1 = [id, name, starttime, startposition],
    event2 = [id2, name2, starttime2, startposition2],
    event3 = [id3, name3, starttime3, startposition3];

//lets join the arrays and stick them in the object
events["fistcolumn"] = event1.concat(event2).concat(event3);  

//now events.fistcolumn (kinky name) contains all the values from the arrays

if (events.fistcolumn[5] == name2) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Because if you want to do like below,

```
 events["fistcolumn"] = events1;
```

events must be an Object.

```
events.push($event1);
events.push($event2);
events.push($event3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var events = new Array(); 
var $event1 = ['id', 'name', 'starttime', 'startposition']; 
var $event2 = ['id2', 'name2', 'starttime2', 'startposition2']; 
var $event3 = ['id3', 'name3', 'starttime3', 'startposition3']; 
events["fistcolumn"] = $event1.concat($event2).concat($event3);
```

I changed those variables to string for testing purposes only, you could change it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
var events = {};  // events object

var $event1 = [id, name, starttime, startposition];
var $event2 = [id2, name2, starttime2, startposition2];
var $event3 = [id3, name3, starttime3, startposition3];
```

then you can either do like this

```
events["fistcolumn"] = [$event1, $event2, $event3];
```

or like this

```
events["fistcolumn"] = [];
events["fistcolumn"].push($event1);
events["fistcolumn"].push($event2);
events["fistcolumn"].push($event3);
```